# Migrate TFS folder into Team Project

Tags: tfs

My organization has been using TFS for years, but has not structured the repository properly.

We currently have a single collection, and a Team Project for every line of business we support. Every Solution is saved as a folder underneath the Team Project. Each Team Project could have dozens of different Solutions saved into it.

We are moving from TFS 2010 to 2012, and I'm taking the opportunity to re-structure our repository.

- Every line of business will have its own collection
- Every Solution will have its own Team Project

It's a grand idea, but the issue is how we are going to migrate the Solutions from 2010 to 2012. Is it possible to somehow retain the history of our code changes, or must we start fresh when we do the migration?

Comment: I'd be wary of this approach, collections are held in separate databases and you cannot branch or merge between collections. You also cannot share work items between collections. Finally you cannot connect to more than 1 collection at the same time with visual studio. If your code structure works within those constraints then fine, but if you have common code that is shared amongst solutions the keeping them all in the same collection will save you hours of frustration.

Comment: Your current structure sounds fine. A team project should be considered a "portfolio" of applications... each individual application should not be a separate team project.

Comment: @DanielMann Given that each team project has a single portal for ALM, how could we keep work items from one solution polluting the portal for developers of another solution?

Comment: @ChrisHardie this is solved by using multiple Teams in the same TeamProject.

Comment: Giulio is right. Of course, the concept of "teams" were added in TFS2012, so that's probably why you're not aware of them.

Comment: @DanielMann thank you for your input. Would you be aware of any documentation that would provide guidance on how to structure our repository? I want to ensure we do everything right when we move to VS 2012. Our needs are to leverage the ALM capabilities for each solution in isolation from the other, completely disctint, solutions we have developed for each line of business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade to TFS 2012 the upgrade process will keep all of your history and work items. Read the [upgrade guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620933%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from Microsoft. You should upgrade before you restructure, it'll be easier that way.

There are basically 2 ways to upgrade, depending on if you plan to run TFS on the same hardware or if you're planning on putting new hardware in to host TFS 2012.

Be aware that [splitting collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isn't strait forward but it is possible, you basically duplicate them and then delete the stuff you don't want to keep. However if you decide that you then want to move Team Projects between collections or merge them then TFS doesn't support this out of the box. You can use the [TFS integration tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) to do this, but it's a far from perfect solution